# kernel programming - Makefile error

Tags: linux-kernel

i am not getting output for this code. What changes have to make in my Makefile??
code:

```
#define MODULE 
#define LINUX
#define __KERNEL__

#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/init.h>``
MODULE_LISENCE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Peter Jay Salzman");


static u8 (mybyte='A');
static int (myint='i');

MODULE_PARM(mybyte, "b");
MODULE_PARM(myint, "i");

MODULE_PARM_DESC(mybyte, "this cannot do anything\n");

static int  __init hello5_init(void)

{
    printk("my byte %i\n",mybyte);
printk("my integer %i \n",myint);
 }
static void __exit hello5_exit()
{
printk("bye world\n");
}
module_init(hell05_init);
module_exit(helo5_exit);
```

Makefile:
    obj-m += hello5.o

```
all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

exit:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean

.PHONY: all, exit
```

Error:

```
 /home/kumarmagi/Desktop/amit/hello5/hello5.c:23:24: error: ‘mybyte’ undeclared     (first       use in this function)
    /home/kumarmagi/Desktop/amit/hello5/hello5.c:23:24: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
    /home/kumarmagi/Desktop/amit/hello5/hello5.c:24:28: error: ‘myint’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    /home/kumarmagi/Desktop/amit/hello5/hello5.c:25:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
MODULE_PARM(mybyte, "b");
MODULE_PARM(myint, "i");
static int (myint='i');
static u8 (mybyte='A');
```

to:

```
module_param(mybyte, short, 0660);
module_param(myint, int, 0660);
static short mybyte='A';
static int myint='i';
```

Comment: do u think the problem is with your compiler?!!!. Problem is with your program, at least paste the program correctly here, do u have the function 'hell05_init' in your program, or do u have the function 'helo5_exit' in the program, is there a way to define a variable like this 'static u8 (mybyte='A')'?.